# Sentry doesn't let me change own settings

Tags: python, sentry

We have 3 teams. I don't want to receive emails for the Mobile team. I am owner (I have set it up) but it didn't let me change the settings. I had to promote another user to edit my settings and then reset him to be just *Member*. 
How can I opt out myself? [image]

Sentry 7.4.3

Answer (score 0):

In your case you're only a team-based owner (you're access is restricted to those two teams).

You'd need an admin of the install (i.e. getsentry.com support, or your ops team), or a global organization owner to correct it.

Comment: I installed it myself. My user is the very first user that's been created via command line (sentry createuser). All (four) checkboxes were checked before. Thats a screenshot from after I did the workaround, giving another user ownership and revoking Mobile access for my user.

Comment: `select is_staff, is_active, is_superuser where username = '<myself>' ` returns three times TRUE